# how to reload cache for all the pods when there are changes in db tables

Tags: spring-boot, caching, openshift, reload

My service is deployed in openshift environment and i am using springboot java to cache the data using @cacheable from four different tables. Now, i have created an endpoint that reloads the cache using @cacheput into these tables but this would refresh the cache only for one pod and not for all 4 pods.

Is there a solution or approach to reload the cache for all 4 pods? I got to know that hazelcast is one of the solution for this. Does anyone have any other thoughts or idea?